# Problem with loading a third party jar inside a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Spring Boot application, for a business reason I need to import a 3rd party jar which also reads some config parameter from a file named **application.properties**.

I have defined all the configs required by my app and the 3rd party jar in the spring boot **application.properties** file.

When I run this application from Eclipse all is well, but when I run it from outside by using command the code inside the jar can't find the **application.properties** file and throws exception;

`java -jar myapp.jar`

when I change it to following command and by placing the **application.properties** file outside the jar it works;

`java -Xbootclasspath/a: -jar myapp.jar`

How can make it work without placing the **application.properties** file from outside the jar?

Some additional Info;
3rd party jar is a lib jar included as my maven dependency. Inside the 3rd Party code there is a place where it's loading **application.properties** file, but throws exception.

```
    Properties cfg = new Properties();
    FileInputStream is = null;

    URL url = DemoApplication.class.getResource("/");
    if (null != url) {

        String configPath = url.getFile()+ "application.properties";
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(configPath);
            cfg.load(is); // It fails here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Exception:

```
file:/D:/Temp/target/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties FAILED load config.java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Temp\target\myapp.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\application.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Comment: would be helpful to see the exception

Comment: Exception is as below: file:/D:/Temp/target/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties
FAILED load config.java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\Temp\target\myapp.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\application.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: Its a maven project , and I do use mv install to generate the package. The package is fine , the failure is because of external jar reading the property file

Comment: How is the Thirdparty jar started? Is the thirdparty jar a mavendependency of your spring boot app? or ist it started seperatly. and how do your try to read the properties in your thirdparty app. Maybe provide some code.

Comment: Third party jar is an external lib included as dependency in my project , I have edited the question to include the code snippet where it fails while loading the application.properties file.

Comment: You can Zip your application.properties file into the jar, so it could be located at `file:/D:/Temp/target/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a maven project, try to use (mvn package) command and then run the jar generated under the target folder

Answer (score 0):

If your thirdparty-app is a maven dependency of myApp you can load it from the classpath:

```
Properties cfg = new Properties();
cfg.load(DemoApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
```

Comment: Sorry I dint understand your point. MyApp is loading the 3rd Party jar; which in turn is loading the application.properties file. I cant change the code of 3rd Party jar

Comment: Well in my eyed it's a wrong design. If this is a closed module it should have it's own config file which you have to place in the desired location (classpath, filesystem etc.). How do you call your third party app?

Comment: yes its unfortunate that 3rd Party jar config file clashes with my app property file. But I have no control over 3rd Party jar and I must include it. If somehow I can make the 3rd party jar read the application.property file from inside the jar my problem will be solved.

Comment: again. how do you call the third party jar

Comment: It has some APIs , I create the instance of the class and call the APIs

Answer (score 0):

That 3rd Party jar uses a FileInputStream with a URL that starts with something derived from Class.getResource(...).

That's never going to work with jar files.

What can work is to skip the FileInputStream, but use Class.getResourceAsStream(...):

```
InputStream is = DemoApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")
```

Comment: Unfortunately Its 3rd party jar code which I cant change.

Comment: How do they do it in other applications, then? They will allways have to add a local directory to the classpath to be able to read a properties file like that. It's not something you can solve then.

Comment: Other apps which use this Lib are spring based app , not spring-boot , they deploy their package as war file, and they are not facing this problem.